# Is the relation < a strict total order?

Tags: abstract-algebra, relations

I really stuck with a question in the class exercise:

Consider the set $X=2^Y$ where $Y=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}$ and the order on X defined by $x < y$ if and only if $x \subset y$, that is if $x$ is a subset of $y$. Is the relation < $x$ strict total order?

Please elaborate a bit on the question. Just started my intro to abstract algebra.

I feel this is not strict total order. But, couldn't find an counter example to it.

Comment: What do you mean by 2^Y

Comment: Just take two disjoint, non-empty, subsets. They are no comparable. Therefore, the order is not [total](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation).

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima In set theory, $X^Y$ usually denotes the set of functions from $Y$ to $X$, and natural numbers (especially $2$) are used to denote a generic (or maybe specific) set with that many elements (this has the nice bonus that, for instance, $3^2$ has $9$ elements). Specifically, $2^Y$ is naturally bijective with the power set of $Y$ (which explains why $2$ is more common than any other number in this application).

Comment: @orole I don't quite understand. The if and only if condition states that $x \subset y$ how do you get two disjoint set? Would you please elaborate?

Comment: You can take the disjoint sets because they are elements of $2^Y$. The if and only if is precisely what makes them not comparable; neither $<$ nor $>$ holds for them.

Comment: Let me know if I'm saying this correctly. $\{\{2\}, \{4, 8, 16\}\} \subset X$. they're not comparable because they're disjoint sets. Example $\{\{2, 4\}, \{4, 8 \}\}$ are not comparable, right?

Comment: In both of these two cases you presented, they're not comparable because neither of the sets is contained in the other. Note that in the second case they are not disjoint (both have $4$) but they're still not comparable.

Comment: Cool!!!! Thank you all!!!! I wonder if all of you guys have taken some sort of abstract algebra class?

Comment: @Salahamam_Fatima That's the power set, the set of all subsets of  $Y$.